# Cloud Run 403: Insufficient scope for certain users while other users work fine

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, authorization, google-cloud-run

I have a **secured** node.js backend running on **cloud run**. One issue I've been having is that some users face a **403 insufficient scope** from "Google Frontend" server, client does not have permission to get URL.

This is strange because it is **not happening to all users**. In fact, one of my test accounts is facing this issue while my actual account is not. To get the auth header, I am using firebase+google identity to get oidc tokens. I compared the oidc tokens between the 2 accounts and everything seems to be the same, that needs to be the same (other than email, sub, hash, etc). iss, aud, azp, hd parts of the **jwt token are all the same**.

I dont 100% understand service accounts, so I think the issue may be with the service account permissions connected to the cloud run service, but the fact that is works for some users and not enough for other users is weird to me.

The main difference I see between the 2 accounts is the cookies:

Working Account:

```
GCP_IAAP_AUTH_TOKEN_F3BA....
__Host-GCP_IAP_AUTH_TOKEN_F3BA....
GCP_IAP_UID
_ga
_ga_K...
_ga_S...
_ga_F...
GCP_IAP_XSRF_NONCE_1vp....
```

403 blocked Request Account:

```
GCP_IAAP_AUTH_TOKEN_F3BA....
__Host-GCP_IAP_AUTH_TOKEN_F3BA....
GCP_IAP_UID
_ga
_ga_F...
```

As you can see, 2 *ga*... cookies are missing (not sure what those are), but more importantly (I believe), the GCP_IAP_XSRF_NONCE_ is missing. Why its missing I have 0 idea since user is successfully through IAP.

**UPDATE**
Nevermind, GCP_IAP_XSRF_NONCE_ was not the issue, still getting 403 for some user accounts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after a couple of days. Turns out that some people didn’t have run.invoker role in cloud run so had create a google group of people I wanted to have access (internal app)